# Can this impeller push the boat to the left?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Can this impeller push the boat to the left? As shown in the figure, this is the impeller of a centrifugal pump installed on the ship. When the impeller rotates, water flows in from the inlet of the impeller, which will generate an axial force to the left (shown by the red arrow). Will this force make the ship move to the left? The green arrow shows a bearing from which the axial force of the impeller is transmitted to the ship.

As shown in the figure, water will generate low pressure in the area indicated by the blue arrow when the impeller rotates.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the type of impeller since there are many impellers with one side closed, preventing the use as a propeller.

[image]

When using such an impeller closed on one side (and probably with most other impellers as well), your ship would start to rotate around its own axis, with the impeller functioning like the wheel of a water mill:

[image]

A funny idea, but probably not what you wanted.